# pixi.js: how is the scrolling done on the website flashvhtml.com?

Tags: animation, pixi.js

How's the page scrolling created on [flashvhtml.com](http://flashvhtml.com)? How is the scrolling triggered by the links at the top and how the other 'sub animation' events tied in to the scrolling background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I have been able to gather:

- Listeners for interactions are added in the `Trackpad.js` file. Listeners for events such as mouse dragging, keyboard events, touch etc. All of which calculating a `value` variable.
- This `value` variable of the `Trackpad.js` is then
  used to adjust `camera` position in the `update` method of `main.js`
  file.
- There are 3 main views that are being rendered if I understand
  it correctly: `ScrollView`, `ScaleView`, `RocketView`. All of those
  initiated inside the `init` method of `main.js`. But they are all
  defined in the `fvh.js` file.
- Each of these three *views* have an
  `updatePosition` method taking `camera.y` or `mainScrollPosition` as
  parameter. These `updatePosition` methods are called inside of the
  same `update` method of `main.js` file.
- Then there is a `ScrollMap.js` which contains loads of position data for all 3 views e.g. it contains `ScrollView` data in the format of:
  `mcxxx:{view:'nameofelement',depth:xx,startFrame:xxx,endFrame:xxx,position:[xxx,...]}` etc.
- Also there is a `sectionLandPositions` variable defined in the `main.js` file which is also very interesting because this is what is then used inside the `onMenuItemPressed` method in the same file to tween and bring a certain section into view.
- So magic basically happens in the `updatePosition` methods of each views and how the value is computed in the `Trackpad.js`. And this is where I leave you to debug further and take it home. :)

Files under scrutiny are: `Trackpad.js`, `fvh.js`, `ScrollMap.js`, `main.js`. Hope you find it all useful.

P.S. Kudos to [Waste-Creative](http://waste-creative.com/) for creating this informative and engaging website.

T

Comment: Thanks Tahir, brilliant answer! Your explanation is really helping me get inside this code.

How do you think they created the scrollMap position points? Seems like a lot to code by hand while tweaking animation - I'm wondering if there's some animation tool out there which they used to get the position points that exported these numbers.

Comment: My guess is [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) or at least it has been used in some capacity in this project but not sure how it can be used for positioning like this. I got to dig deep before giving you a definitive answer on this. I'll try to dig it further if I have time and hopefully this magic will unravel itself too :) Hopefully :). It sure is fun to walk through someone's else code, NOT :D

Comment: @TahirAhmed you're a legend sir, thanks for the comprehensive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this, is by adding [tweens](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweening) and then using the scroll/drag input and links to move around in the tween's timeline.

- Tween one : Pans Camera down slowly continuously.
- Tween two : Wait's until x, fades sprite in untily y, fades sprite out, ..

Make sure, you dont 'play' the tween's after creating them, but adjust the time manually (based on the scroll position).

There are a few tweeing frameworks you can use for pixi: [Greensocks](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/), [Impact](https://github.com/nefD/impact-tween), [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js)
And there's a discusion on it over at the [html5gamedevs forum.](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/938-tweening/)